# font-safe alphabet

Tags: fonts, character, typeface

I'm wondering, is there a known "font safe" alphabet? I tried googling this to no avail.

Considering that I want to use a string (e.g. a serial number), that consists of a mixture of either case English characters, and numbers. I would like to avoid having characters that can be misinterpreted as other characters. For example, I would like to avoid using `O` (capital o) and `0` (zero), because in certain fonts they can be confused. The same goes for `1` (one) and `l` (minuscule l). Nothing else jumps to mind, so I was wondering if there a full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer could be to generate the key with safe characters. Something like the below C++ code:

```
static const char alphabet[] = 
      // no l (similar to 1) or Z (similar to 2) or O (similar to 0) inside
     "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ACDEFGHIJKLMNPQRTUVWXY";
std::string randkey;
cont inst keylen = 24;
while (randkey.length () < keylen)
  randkey.append(alphabet[(random() & 0xfffffff) % sizeof(alphabet)]);
```

I'm not sure you should seek a "safe font" because that font might not be available on the client browser (unless you are printing on paper, in which case you should ensure to have the font when printing).

And "font safety" is a relative concept: a blind person, a person with bad eyes, even a tired person is reading font differently.

Comment: thank you, that's basically what I was looking for. I got 2 out of 3 then :)

Comment: You might consider that `6` and `G` are also similar. I find them different enough. YMMV

Comment: Somebody should crowdsource that in different fonts :)

Comment: Since all available chars will not fill 6 bits, I came up with this base32 alphabet:
01234689ABCDEHJKLMNPSTUWXabfmpry, in attempt to reduce confusion to the minimum.

Comment: And my intent is not to make it proof for disabled folk. Rather minimize the error rate when the data is copied over by hands. Somebody who's tired, and has been doing this for all day :)